# Google Apps Script modal dialog is not working for one user

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

EDIT: This issue appears to only happen when using Chrome.  If we use Edge, it works.

I've recreated the issue [on this page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R8p1JsZjRgGcBWbeYhzOq8CH15LzISLrrK0l8eYHXH8/edit#gid=0).  For myself and secondary dummy account, this works fine, but it does not work for another user.

I have two server-side functions

1. showModal(): shows a modal dialog box
2. getDinner(): returns 'potatoes'

I have a button which runs showModal().  On first run, I'm asked to authorize the script as expected.  Once authorized, I click the button and I see the modal dialog box with some pre-configured text, "steak and ".  I call the getDinner() function with client-side google.script.run  which returns 'potatoes' and inserts it into the span element, after "and" which makes the full sentence "steak and potatoes".

After my affected user authorizes the script in the same way I do, he clicks on the button and the modal dialog box appears, but getDinner() never runs.  I confirm this in the project executions page.  They're just left with "steak and ".  We tried revoking the access and re-authorizing but that didn't seem to do anything.

**Code.gs file**

```
function showModal(){
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('template');
  templ = templ.evaluate().setWidth(1500).setHeight(793);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(templ,'Here\s what I had for Dinner:');
}

function getDinner(){
  return 'potatoes'
}
```

**template.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showDinner).getDinner();

      function showDinner(dinner){
        document.getElementById("side").innerHTML = dinner
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Steak and <span id="side"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```